# receive and return a file from spring boot rest API

Tags: spring-boot

How do I write an endpoint in Spring Boot that does the following?

1. receives a file of any extension
2. returns another file of any extension (which is an encrypted version of input file)

As of now, all I know with spring is to input and output JSON or query params, etc, but nothing like a file...

My first though is to send the file as a binary string, make my changes to it and then return it back as a String as well. But if I did that, the browser wouldn't download that response automatically.

I'm kinda lost, any help is appreciated!

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/encode")
public class EncodeController {

     @PostMapping("/v1")
     public ??? encodeFile( ??? file ) {
        File encoded file = encode(file);
        return encoded;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/encode")
public class EncodeController {

     @PostMapping("/v1")
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
     public ResponseEntity<File> encodeFile(MultipartFile file) {
        File encodedFile = encode(file);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(encodedFile)
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + encodedFile.getName() + "\"" )
            .build();
    } 
}
```